# Combobox SeletedItem does not wok ( Winform c# 3.5)

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Create a Form, add a combobox in it, then paste :

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        TimeZoneInfo myZome = TimeZoneInfo.Local;

        comboBox1.DataSource = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
        comboBox1.SelectedItem = myZome;
    }
```

ComboBox will display only the first element, it does not care about selectedItem...
this driving me nuts
any help please ?
Thanks in advance
Fred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instance of your timezone object (myZome) is not in the zones list. 
Find the right one in the collection.

Try this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ICollection<TimeZoneInfo> zoneList = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
    TimeZoneInfo myZone = zoneList.First<TimeZoneInfo>(t => t.Id == TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id);
    comboBox1.DataSource = zoneList;
    comboBox1.SelectedItem = myZone;
}
```